# Inequality of sequence numbers

Tags: calculus

I have to find such $N$ that $n>N$ and the following inequality is satisfied by sequence's $n$-th members.
$x_n=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $|x_n-1|<0,1$. I got that $1,5^\frac{1}{n}>0,9$, but I think this is satisfied by all natural $n$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. For $n\geq 2$, let $t_n=n^{1/n}-1>0$. Then
$$n=(t_n+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} t_n^k\geq 1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}t_n^2\implies \frac{2}{n}\geq t_n^2.$$